# How to find the relative position of visual vocabulary in an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, sift

I have created a dictionary of visual words with size 20. The following shows an array of word frequency in a specific image:

```
[ 3.  2.  1.  3.  3.  ...  2.  2.  3.  1.  3.  .....      2.  1. ]
```

I count the the number of times that a specific visual vocabulary is observed in an image:

```
unique, counts = np.unique(A[:,img_idx], return_counts=True)  #
dict(zip(unique, counts))  
OUT: {0.0: 47,
     1.0: 89,
     2.0: 89,
     3.0: 79,
     4.0: 42,
     5.0: 25,
     6.0: 10,
     7.0: 12,
     8.0: 3,
     9.0: 2,
     10.0: 1,
     11.0: 1}   #Here, 11 visual vocab. has been observed in image
```

How can I find relative position of each visual vocabulary in an image? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could display the relative position of each visual word through [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/).

First import the necessary modules:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then generate mock data (`visual_words`is actually the output of your feature extractor):

```
dict_size = 5
img_shape = (9, 16)
visual_words = np.random.randint(low=0, high=dict_size, size=img_shape)
```

And finally display the spatial arrangement of features throughout the image:

```
cmap = plt.get_cmap('rainbow', dict_size)
im = plt.imshow(visual_words, cmap=cmap, vmin=-.5, vmax=dict_size-.5)
plt.colorbar(im, ticks=range(dict_size), label='Visual words')
plt.show()
```

[image: Map of visual words]